# Connection problem to Luis service using SDK v4

Tags: c#, sdk, bots, azure-language-understanding

I have a problem when I try to connect my bot to LUIS service using the code in BotBuilder-Samples-master.

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples

I'm using the Microsoft Bot Builder SDK v4.

**I followed below documentation**: To add LUIS service to recognize intents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

When I write a message to a bot, an exception is thrown at this line of code in the LuisBot.cs file:

```
var recognizerResult = await _services.LuisServices[LuisKey].RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

and this error comes out:

> Message = "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"
>   Stack Trace= “at
>   Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.d__21.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line
>   358\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n

Has anyone had this same error?

Comment: not sure what that error in particular means, but if you're just running the sample 12.nlp-with-luis from the C# repo, all you need to do is fill in the values of appId and authoringKey in your .bot file for service of type "luis" (you could delete subscriptionKey when not in production).

Comment: Also assisted someone who had issues with getting the node version of the bot set up, but you can see bulleted items for suggestions on what to check for in your bot here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/848

Comment: Oh and one more thing that is a common mistake: be sure to PUBLISH your LUIS app as well in the luis portal